# Android : Fatal error Not a git repository

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing the below error from Android studio project.

`Error:Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128`

I was downloading source from `VCS->Git`, and cancelled it in the middle. Then I downloaded the same source locally and 'open existing android studio project' option. Once this project is opened in studio, I couldn't run it at all. It is still throwing error as below.

> Error:fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories):
>   .git
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script '/Users/.../functions.gradle' line: 19
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project '..'.
>
>   > Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I tried cleaning the project and run, observed the same error.

I again downloaded the same project from `VCS->Git` completely, still observing the same error either cases.

Could someone guide me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can from the terminal, access the root of your projet then do:

```
git init
```

It will initialise your project as a git project, then try again and tell us what you have

Comment: I did this from terminal. And then opening the same project in studio, will throw the same error. not able to run this project.

Comment: Even if i delete the project, and download or git again, the same issue has been observed. I did clean project and try as well.